# Books about exponential tilting

Tags: probability, inequality, book-recommendation, concentration-of-measure

Please recommend books about the expoential tilting. My main insterest is about its application on concentration inequalities. Søren Asmussen's Stochastic Simulation: Algorithms and Analysis have explanation about exponential tilting but is not about its application on concentration inequalities.